# xquery count for loop inside a for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, count, xquery

xquery i would like to count the loop element data 
Code:

```
    declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'xml';
declare option output:indent 'yes';

let $act :=(
<act time="1231">
 <data>hel1lo</data>
 <data>hel1lo</data>
</act>,
<act time="51292">
 <data>world</data>
 <data>wo2rld2</data>
 <data>world2</data>
</act>
)
for $data in $act
return
<act time ="{$data/@time}">
    {
    for $count at $cnt in $data/data
    return
    <data value ="{$count}">{$cnt}</data>

    }
</act>

(:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<act time="1231">
   <data value="hel1lo">1</data>
   <data value="hel1lo">2</data>
</act>
<act time="51292">
   <data value="world">1</data>
   <data value="wo2rld2">2</data>
   <data value="world2">3</data>

</act>

because i need data from act element as well


exptected:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<act time="1231">
   <data value="hel1lo">1</data>
   <data value="hel1lo">2</data>
</act>
<act time="51292">
   <data value="world">3</data>
   <data value="wo2rld2">4</data>
   <data value="world2">5</data>
</act>


:)
```

Code HERE : https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoE/3

the problem is. I need it to be in the secoundery loop but i would like to know how to continue the first count in there. It needs to be loop inside of the loop

Comment: These are `for` expressions, not loops. Why can't you simply use `for $data at $cnt in $act/act return <data>{$cnt}</data>`? Why do you need to nest two `for` expressions?

Comment: because i need them in  as <act><data>1</data></act> <act><data>2</data></act>  i need to count them like as

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, the `let` you have is not valid XQuery. See whether https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kC helps, otherwise edit your question and provide a minimal but valid XML input together with the output you want.

Comment: to undrestand what i wanna achieve :https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoE/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use all elements in the inner `for .. at` so that the variable bound in the `at` clause has the right value relative to the whole sequence but to then add a `where` clause `where $count/.. is $data` before the return that ensures we process only those items that have the right parent i.e. where the parent element is the currently processed `$data` item:

```
let $act :=(
<act time="1231">
 <data>hel1lo</data>
 <data>hel1lo</data>
 <data>hel231lo</data>
 <data>hel1lo</data>
 <data>hel12lo</data>
 <data>hel1lo</data>
 <data>hel123lo</data>
</act>,
<act time="51292">
 <data>world</data>
 <data>wo2rld2</data>
 <data>world2</data>
 <data>worl2d</data>
 <data>worl1d</data>
 <data>worl2d</data>
</act>
)
for $data in $act
return
<act time ="{$data/@time}">
    {
    for $count at $cnt in $act/data
    where $count/.. is $data
    return
    <data value ="{$count}">{$cnt}</data>

    }
</act>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoE/4

Comment: Can you please explain in the proverbial "plain English"  how `where $count/.. is $data` achieves what OP asked for?

Comment: @JackFleeting, see the edit, I am not sure you just think the answer needs to be improved with an explanation or whether you want to point out it is wrong.

Comment: No, nothing's wrong. I'm really just trying to wrap my head around this... And the explanation is indeed helpful. Thanks for that.

Comment: @MartinHonnen one more question , could it be passable like so https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoE/5 somehow ?

Comment: @GWL, consider to ask follow-up questions as new questions where you explain in the question text which input you have, which result you want, which code you have tried and in what way it fails. Feel free to also link to a fiddle but it is hard to solely understand your new requirement from a link to a fiddle.

Comment: @MartinHonnen follow up question if u have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397444/xquery-count-for-expressions-in-a-for-expressions